# MYSQL multiple keyword search only returning results of first keyword

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The issue seems to be when I search for multiple keywords, only the first keyword result is returned.

For instance, if my keyword search was `algebra, calculus, geometry`, the search results are only inserting rows that are relevant to the `algebra` keyword. I'm really at a loss for this one, because when I enter the same query (minus the insert) in `phpmyadmin` I get the full results. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Below is the code snippet:

```
$kw = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "searchBar");
$keywordArray = explode(",", $kw);
$counter = 0;
$keywordSearch = "";


$keywordQuery = "SELECT problem.pid, problem.content, keyword.keyword FROM problem "
                . "LEFT JOIN probkey_mapping ON probkey_mapping.pid = problem.pid "
                . "LEFT JOIN keyword ON probkey_mapping.keyid = keyword.keyid WHERE keyword.keyword IN ('";


$keywordQuery .= implode("','", $keywordArray) . "')";
$keywordQuery .= "ORDER BY keyword.keyword";
$insertResultsQuery = "INSERT INTO search_results "
                          . "$keywordQuery";
mysqli_query($conn, $insertResultsQuery);
```

Comment: one echo $insertResultsQuery before mysqli_query and see?

Comment: Please, attach the tables schema.